# color polyline based geojson property in leaflet

Tags: if-statement, colors, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to style (color) my leaflet polyline (geojson object showing a trail) based on some conditions. The condition is the average speed, which is calculated from a timestamp that comes with the geojson. Thanks to this forum, I managed to show the line as expected. But the styling does not work.
The average speed of the example data ist 1.3 km/h, thus the line should be red. But it is blue.
Maybe that is because the polyline is created before the velocitiy was calculated.
But adding that code line later does not work because the calculation of the distance depends on that polyline. Or what ist my mistake?
Any hints how to get that styling right?
Thanks in advance.
Here is a simplified code;

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <!-- Load leaflet library and use its styling css        -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js">  </script>
    
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/measuredDistance.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />  //not included
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pagewrapper">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //add map and set view
    var map =  L.map('map').setView([48.8,13.03],6);
      
    // add background layer "opentopomap"
    var backgroundlayer = L.tileLayer ('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    map.addLayer(backgroundlayer);
  
    //get geojson data
var geojsondata = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.0908549980086,
          47.812500986468
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Source": 2,
        "ele": 399.0844,
        "time": 1174816297000,
        "ObjectId": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.0408219980085,
          47.812484986468
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Source": 2,
        "ele": 397.1617,
        "time": 1174826310000,
        "ObjectId": 2
      }
    }]};


    function myFunction() {
             visualizer.sendDataToMap(geojsondata)
        };

    //---------------------------------------------               
//styling function for polyline, depending on velocitiy of track     
function restylemap(feature) {
        if(velocitiy <= 4) {
              return{color: "red"}
            }
          else if (velocitiy > 4 && velocitiy <= 20) {return 
            {color:"green"}
            }
          else {return {color:"grey"}}
            };
      
      // function to calculate total time of track
      function sum(array) {
      return Number(array[array.length - 1] - Number(array[0]));
      };
//----------------------------------------------------
        
var visualizer = {};
         visualizer.sendDataToMap = function (jsonData) {{
          L.geoJson(jsonData 
          )};
        // read coordinates from geojson object
          const latlngs = jsonData.features.map((feature) => [
            feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
            feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
          ]);
           //access time information from geojson object
          const time = jsonData.features.map((feature) => [
            feature.properties.time
          ]);
          
          //create polyline from coordinates and style according to function "restylemap"
          var linie = L.polyline(latlngs, {style:restylemap});
          
          //calculate total distance of polyline
          var lengthInMeters = linie.measuredDistance();
          
          //remove non numeric chars ("km") from string 
          var distance = lengthInMeters.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''); 
          
          //calculate time between first and last timestamp
          var elapstime = (sum(time) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
          
          //Calculate average speed on track
          var velocitiy = distance/elapstime

          //add polyline to map
          linie.addTo(map);

          // center map to polyline
          map.fitBounds(linie.getBounds()); 

          //avespeed.toFixed(1)
          alert("Velocitiy: "+velocitiy.toFixed(1)+" km/h");
        };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, you add the style to early. Change your code to:

```
//styling function for polyline, depending on velocitiy of track     
function restylemap(velocitiy) {  // <-------- NEW
        if(velocitiy <= 4) {
              return{color: "red"}
            }
          else if (velocitiy > 4 && velocitiy <= 20) {return 
            {color:"green"}
            }
          else {return {color:"grey"}}
};
```

```
    //create polyline from coordinates and style according to function "restylemap"
          var linie = L.polyline(latlngs);  // <-------- NEW
          
          //calculate total distance of polyline
          var lengthInMeters = linie.measuredDistance();
          
          //remove non numeric chars ("km") from string 
          var distance = lengthInMeters.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''); 
          
          //calculate time between first and last timestamp
          var elapstime = (sum(time) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
          
          //Calculate average speed on track
          var velocitiy = distance/elapstime

          // Change line color
          linie.setStyle(restylemap(velocitiy)); // <-------- NEW

          //add polyline to map
          linie.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you, that code line worked. Additionally I had to make the var velocity available outside the function. Thus I skipped the "var" and did just `velocitiy = distance/elapstime`. I know this is not advised, but I did not find another way to make the variable velocitiy  available outside the function it was created. So if there is a better way, I´d be happy to know.

Comment: Why you need `velocity` outside? you can pass it to the function `restylemap(velocitiy)` directly

Comment: ..mmhh not sure what you mean... velocity is calculated within this function  `var visualizer = {};         visualizer.sendDataToMap = function (jsonData) {{ ......    `.  But then i want to use it for this function: `function restylemap(velocitiy) { ....` which I declared outside. Without skipping the "var" in front of velocity I got an error --> "not defined"